# Dynamically create views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a chat application in angular js. It contains two views

1. userList view (shows list of users)
2. messageActivity view (shows recent messages, kind of chat screen)

Right now, It has single static view and route.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
        controller: 'userController'
      }) 
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
```

**user.html**

It shows the list of online users.

When user click on username of list, it should create the unique dynamic view of messageActivity based on userId. There can be 100 users. Creating 100 views is not possible. So, views has to be unique and dynamic. I created the basic template of messageActivity. 
Is this possible in angularjs?

Comment: you may need to use regx inside your `.when('/chat/{regx}'` keep same template for all, load there data using id from the url

Answer (score 0):

Pass the user ID as a route param.

```
 .when('/user/:userId',
```

In your user link, use /user/{{userId}} , where userId is a unique user identifier, preferably numeric.

You can the pass the $routeParams service into your controller and get the userId